# how to make two validation at a time with two result

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery

I have created a validation with two checkbox.

both validations are working fine with javascript

let me show you my code

javascipt

```
function Validation_agree(){
    if(document.form1.agreed1.checked==false)
    {
        $(".agreement_main").show();
        return false
    }else{
        $(".agreement_main").hide();
    }

    if(document.form1.agreed2.checked==false)
    {
        $(".agreement_terms").show();
        return false
    }else{
        $(".agreement_terms").hide();
    }
}
```

form is like

```
 <div class="checkme">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="" name="agreed1" />I have discussed all of the order details above and the customer is happy to proceed</label>
<br />
  <div class="alert agreement_main" style="display:none;">Please confirm you have informed the customer of the T&amp;Cs</div>
</div>

 <div class="redNote">
 <label><input type="checkbox" value="" name="agreed2" />I have informed the customer where they can find the T&C’s on the BT.com website</label></p>
 <div class="alert agreement_terms" style="display:none;">Please confirm you have informed the customer of the T&amp;Cs</div>
 </div>


 <input type="submit" value="submit order" /></div>
</form>
```

the problem is that. one is working after vadating other one
When press submit button shows first validation error message. I would like to make both validation check at a time

any one help me please 
thanks in advance

Comment: I'm facing similar problem with one of my application :(

Comment: @maanu you can use use answer from JQone, which is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code may work for you.

```
function Validation_agree(){       
 var isValid = true;
 if(document.form1.agreed1.checked==false)       
  {           
      $(".agreement_main").show();           
         isValid = false;
   }else
    {           
      $(".agreement_main").hide();       
    }          
   if(document.form1.agreed2.checked==false)       
    {           
      $(".agreement_terms").show();           
       isValid = false;      
     }else{           
       $(".agreement_terms").hide();       
      }   
      return isValid;
}
```